# Why can't I embed these Applications in my Form?

Tags: c#, winapi, process, embed, handler

### Intention

Using the following code, I managed to load some applications in my windows form.

### Code

What this function does is...

- stating a process
- embedding the process into a panel of my form
- maximizing the embedded process
- adding a resize event handler to the panel to update the size of the embedded process on panel resize
- adding a closed event handler to the form to terminate the embedded process on form close

Usings

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Constants

```
const int   GWL_STYLE   = -16;
const long  WS_VISIBLE  = 0x10000000,
            WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000,
            WS_BORDER   = 0x00800000,
            WS_CHILD    = 0x40000000;
```

Function

```
IntPtr LoadExtern(Control Panel, string Path)
{
    try
    {
        Process Process = Process.Start(Path);
        Process.WaitForInputIdle();
        IntPtr Handle = Process.MainWindowHandle;
        SetParent(Handle, Panel.Handle);
        SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, (int)(WS_VISIBLE+(WS_MAXIMIZE|WS_BORDER)));

        MoveWindow(Handle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height, true);

        Panel.Resize += new EventHandler(
             delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                  MoveWindow(Handle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height, true);
             }
        );

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(
             delegate(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
                  SendMessage(Handle, 83, 0, 0);
                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
                  Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
             }
        );

        return Handle;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(this, e.Message, "Error"); }
    return new IntPtr();
}
```

DLL Imports

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

### Result

This code works nice with some applications, like the windows notepad. Notepad is started and included in the panel of my form. There is no caption and the are no borders, as it should be.

```
LoadExtern(panel1, "notepad.exe");
```

After closing the form the embedded process gets terminated like expected.

### Problem

Unfortunately my code doesn't work for some other (bigger) applications like firefox or sublimetext.

```
LoadExtern(panel2, @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe");
```

What happens is that my form starts and firefox starts, but in its own window. Could you help me to include sublimetext or firefox in my applications?

### Part of the solution

Thanks to Sheng Jiang's answers, I got it working for some more applications. What I did is to wait for a main window handle.

```
Process.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr Handle = new IntPtr();
for (int i = 0; Handle == IntPtr.Zero && i < 300; i++)
{
     Handle = Process.MainWindowHandle;
     Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

But I still can't embed applications like the windows explorer.

Comment: The only way that this can generally work is *if* the other program is part of the act - it may not be written to expect that one or more of its windows aren't top level windows (which is fairly reasonable - why should those developers expend effort on something they don't expect to happen?)

Comment: What do you mean by "But I still can't embed applications like the windows explorer." - do you mean that you want to embed explorer, but cannot, or that you've seen explorer embed other applications, and you want to do the same (but still, include by reference my previous comments - it's not going to work)

Comment: I want a file explorer window embedded in my form. Unfortunately I can't work together with the developers of the processes I would like to embed.

Comment: Well, as I said - these programs haven't necessarily been built to expect to be embedded in other programs. You may want it, but it doesn't mean it's true or available.

Comment: THe `MainWindowHandle` may not be what you expect. As a test, you get the `hWnd` using another tool (spy++) and embed that to see if that works, if so, you'll need to enumerate the windows int hat process to find the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for most applcations. I embedded the file explorer simply using a webbrowser control on my form and set its url to a file location. The internet explorer control magically turns into a file explorer then.

This is my final code, feel free to use this for you own projects.

```
IntPtr EmbedProcess(Control Panel, string Path)
{
    string Name = NameFromPath(Path);

    foreach (Process Task in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (NameFromPath(Task.ProcessName).Contains(Name))
        {
            try { Task.Kill(); }
            catch (Exception e) {  }
        }
    }

    try
    {
        Process Task = Process.Start(Path);
        Task.WaitForInputIdle();
        IntPtr Handle = new IntPtr();
        for (int i = 0; Handle == IntPtr.Zero && i < 10; i++) { Handle = Task.MainWindowHandle; Thread.Sleep(100); }
        SetParent(Handle, Panel.Handle);
        SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, (int)(WS_VISIBLE + (WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_BORDER)));

        MoveWindow(Handle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height, true);

        Panel.Resize += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { MoveWindow(Handle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height, true); });

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage(Handle, 83, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        });

        return Handle;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(this, e.Message, "Error"); }
    return new IntPtr();
}
```

I somebody is interested in the hole C# classes for embedding window processes and console processes into your form, check out [this github repository](https://github.com/pfisrik/ConsoleDevelopmentEnvironment/tree/master/ConsoleDevelopmentEnvironment/Classes).

Answer (score 3):

Your code worked nice by coincidence.

- WaitForInputIdle wouldn't necessary wait for the UI thread. For example an input method or a hook created by some other program may create a simple thread that becomes idle while the UI thread is still busy doing initialization.
- MainWindowHandle searches for the first visible top level window. It won't return the logical main window when

  - The main window is not the first visible window created (e.g. a login dialog is created first)
  - The main window is not created with the visible style (think about a program that has only an icon in the notification area on the system tray)
  - There is no main window created at all (e.g. some applications open new documents/urls in an existing instance, like browsers and Windows Explorer)
  - There isn't a main window but multiple top level windows that have equal status. Think about IE6/Outlook/Word.

Even if the main window is created visibly and in fact is the first visible window in the new process, you may still have issues.

From the documentation of SetParent:

An application can use the SetParent function to set the parent window of a pop-up, overlapped, or child window.

It does not say you can reparent a top level window. In fact the top level window offers a lot of services that the program may be relying on, such as

- Act as the measuring tool to determine if a full screen request is complete (conflicts with your requirement that new program needs to appear inside your panel)
- Getting notified when a new DDE conversation starts, when the active window/program changes, when new hardware arrives, when system setting changes, when the user is logging off, when Windows Explorer is started, when the user pressed the Enter key on a nested dialog, etc. The list of window messages that only sent to top level windows is too long to list here,
- Act as the default owner window of modal dialogs if the program choose to (and if you display modal dialog in your program as well, [watch out for crashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/23/378866.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can now implement sublimetext using a code that waits for a main handler.